# how to get jquery on() to work on not-yet-existing elements

Tags: jquery

I have always used delegate() to bind events to elements which don't exist when the DOM is initially loaded. I understand that on() is supposed to replace delegate, but I don't understand the documentation on the jquery site how exactly I would translate the following code to use with on()

```
$(document).delegate(
            ".Course_Name, .Start_Date, .Book_Title, .Book_Author, .Book_Isbn",
                "click",
                function()
                {
                    var whichButton = $(this).attr("class");
                    make_table(whichButton);
                    fillISBN();
                });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click",
            ".Course_Name, .Start_Date, .Book_Title, .Book_Author, .Book_Isbn",
                function()
                {
                    var whichButton = $(this).attr("class");
                    make_table(whichButton);
                    fillISBN();
                });
```

Not too hard, was it?

Internally nowdays `.delegate` is just a reference to `.on`. `.delegate` is implemented as

```
function (selector, types, data, fn) {
    return this.on(types, selector, data, fn);
}
```

Comment: It's like teletubbies. Again! Again! Change the API again!

Comment: @ErikReppen Hey man, where have you been? Haven't seen you in the chat in a while. Also, being fair `.on` is the right way, it makes a lot more sense than `.live` or using `.delegate` and it's a better unified API.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try that. My recollection was that at some point in time I tried that and it didn't work so I stayed with delegate...

Comment: @user1015214 While that wasn't the case a while ago, with newer versions of jQuery `.delegate` is coded as a single `.on` call (like my answer indicates (so you shouldn't have any issues). If you feel this solved your issue, please consider accepting this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Benamin showed you what to do. Here is an explanation of *why*.

Basically the principle is to instead of attach the listener directly to the selector, you attach it to some parent object of the selector, and take advantage of event bubbling.  A lot of people do this to `body` or `document` since all objects are below them.  So you attach the event listener to some high level object in the DOM that all present and future elements you want to act on are under, and the click event bubbles up to that object.  Then the 2nd argument to `.on()` is the selector(s) which acts like a filter.

So IOW instead of:

`.delegate()` - Attach listeners to present instances of this selector..and then basically keep looking for instances of these (which is decreased performance).  Order is Select > Attach.

You have

`.on()` - Attach a single listener to this one high level thing and then only act on child elements that match the selector (increased performance).  This effectively makes it work for future elements because the higher level object was/is always there, and that's what the event is attached to. The order is Attach > Select.  The increased performance is because with this method, jQuery doesn't have to keep looking for new instances of the selector(s) to attach event(s) to.

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing `.delegate` with `.live` in this case? The difference between `.delegate` and `.on` is just syntactic sugar and order of parameters to keep the library consistent within itself. While it's more concise to say "what" you're doing and only then "what on" in `.on` I think it's generally the only difference.